# Остается ли лосось свежим и полезным при транспортировке?

Tags: пунктуация

> Остается ли лосось(,) свежим и полезным при транспортировке?

Cтавится ли в этом случае запятая?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, ставить запятую здесь не нужно: нет ни одного основания для ее постановки.

Остается свежим и полезным – это сказуемое; разделять его с помощью знаком пунктуации не нужно.